# UNIX, compare the 1st field File3 with the 1st field of File 2

Tags: filemanager

Suppose I am having three input files as shown below:

```
File 1
 1001 1 2 3 
 1002 4 5 6 
 1003 7 8 9
 1004 10 11 12 

File 2
 1001 11 22 33 
 1002 44 55 66
 1004 100 111 122  

File 3
 1001 111 222 333 
 1004 130 141 152
```

I would like to compare the first field of File3 with the first field of File 2. If a particular first field in File 2 doesn’t exist in File 3, then I want to delete that entire row in File 2.

For example, first field on Row 2 of File 2 (=1002) doesn’t exist in File 3. Hence I want to delete this row in File 2 and save it.

Now I want to compare File 3 and File 1. We see that the first field of second row (=1002) and the first field of the third row (=1003) of File 1 doesn’t exist in File 3.

I want to delete these two rows from File 1 and save it.

After the above steps, the three files would result as the following:

```
File 1
 1001 1 2 3
 1004 10 11 12  

File 2
 1001 11 22 33
 1004 100 111 122 

 File 3
 1001 111 222 333 
 1004 130 141 152
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++; next} $1 in a {print > FILENAME ".tmp"}' File3 File2 File1
```

and then

```
mv File1.tmp File1
mv File2.tmp File2
```

---

If you have a recent enough version of GNU Awk (aka `gawk`) then you can just do:

```
awk -i inplace 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++} !($1 in a) {next} 1' File3 File2 File1
```

Ex.

```
$ awk -i inplace 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++} !($1 in a) {next} 1' File3 File2 File1

$ head File{1..3}
==> File1 <==
 1001 1 2 3 
 1004 10 11 12

==> File2 <==
 1001 11 22 33 
 1004 100 111 122

==> File3 <==
 1001 111 222 333 
 1004 130 141 152
```

Comment: I'm not a whiz at `awk`, but I have been using it for many years and I can't quite see what you're doing. Please elaborate. This may be why you don't have any upvotes for what is probably an elegant answer.  We don't know if the OP is a newbie or just new here, but it's probably a good idea to assume the former. Also, the OP's files are sorted, but the question doesn't say they have to be. If you're assuming that, you should say so.